# typescript class object storing to firebase db

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, typescript-class

I define a typescript class as below:

```
export class UserModel{
    private _name:string
    private _email:string
    private _userId:string
    private _teamId:string
    private _avatar:string
    private _teamName:string

    constructor(name:string, email:string, userId:string, teamId:string, avatar:string, teamName:string){
        this._name = name
        this._email = email
        this._userId = userId
        this._teamId = teamId
        this._avatar = avatar
        this._teamName = teamName
    }

    get name():string{
        return this._name
    }

    set name(val:string){
        this._name = val
    }

    get email():string{
        return this._email
    }

    set email(val:string){
        this._email = val
    }

    get userId():string{
        return this._userId
    }

    set userId(val:string){
        this._userId = val
    }

    get teamId():string{
        return this._teamId
    }

    set teamId(val:string){
        this._teamId = val
    }

    get avatar():string{
        return this._avatar
    }

    set avatar(val:string){
        this._avatar = val
    }

    get teamName():string{
        return this._teamName
    }
}
```

fields are made private and access using getter and setters. This works fine except that when i store the object into firebase db it stores it with the _  e.g

```
{
"_name":"vik,
"_email": "blas@gmal.com"
...
}
```

This breaks my overall code as when i render it back next time then my property names have changed now from name to _name.

Is there a way that when i persist this object to firebase then it stores it without _

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write code to map all the object values into an object that has the exact field names you want to store in the database.  The Firebase SDK provides no shortcut for this, other than what you write to make it easy.

Comment: ah that's a pain then to really keep it useful. what's your opinion do u see it is worth dealing it with conversions or should i go back to remove underscore

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably suffer a long and painfull death in TypeScript hell, but this is my approach to recursively create objects from class instances before saving to Firestore. I told myself that it's OK to be sloppy for this - and only this - TypeScript method since it's the last step before leaving the TypeScript world anyways.

Core method:

```
function toObjectRecursive (a: {[key: string]: any}) : object {
  a = Object.assign({}, a);

  const keys = Object.keys(a);

  const okObjectConstructorNames = [
    "function Array() { [native code] }",
    "function Object() { [native code] }"
  ]

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const val = getProperty(a, key)
    const typename = typeof val;
    const constructor = val !== undefined && val !== null ? val.constructor.toString() : "";

    if (typename === "object" && okObjectConstructorNames.indexOf(constructor) === -1) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      setProperty(a, key, toObjectRecursive(a[key]))
    }
  }

  return a;
}
```

You'll also need two helpers (I'll update the citation)

```
export function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T> (o: T, propertyName: string): T[K] {
  return (o[propertyName as K]); // o[propertyName] is of type T[K]
}

export function setProperty<T, K extends keyof T> (o: T, propertyName: string, val: T[K]) {
  o[propertyName as K] = val; // o[propertyName] is of type T[K]
}
```